# Как убрать из основной логики input() для команд p, s и поместить input() внутрь функций people() и shelf()?

Tags: python

```
    {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
    {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
    {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
]
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
}


def people(doc):
    result = ' - Документ не существует.'
    for document in documents:
        if document["number"] == doc:
            result = f' - Владелец: {document["name"]}'
    print(result)


def shelf(doc):
    result = ' - Документ не существует.'
    for shelf_number, doc_number_ in directories.items():
        if doc in doc_number_:
            return f' - Полка №: {shelf_number}'
    print(result)

while True:
    choice = input('\n- Какую операцию вы хотите выполнить?\n\n'
                   '- p: команда, по номеру документа выведет имя человека, которому он принадлежит\n'
                   '- s: команда, по номеру документа выведет номер полки, на которой он находится\n'
                   '- q: команда, для завершение работы\n').lower()
    if choice == 'p':
        people(input(' - Введите номер документа: '))
    elif choice == 's':
        shelf(str(input(' - Введите номер документа: ')))
    elif choice == 'q':
        print(' - До скорой встречи!')
        break
    else:
        print(' - Неизвестная команда, попробуйте выбрать из списка:')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
documents = [
    {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
    {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
    {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
]
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
}


def people():
    doc = input(' - Введите номер документа: ')
    result = ' - Документ не существует.'
    for document in documents:
        if document["number"] == doc:
            result = f' - Владелец: {document["name"]}'
            break
    print(result)


def shelf():
    doc = input(' - Введите номер документа: ')
    result = ' - Документ не существует.'
    for shelf_number, doc_number_ in directories.items():
        if doc in doc_number_:
            result = f' - Полка №: {shelf_number}'
            break
    print(result)


while True:
    choice = input('\n- Какую операцию вы хотите выполнить?\n\n'
                   '- p: команда, по номеру документа выведет имя человека, которому он принадлежит\n'
                   '- s: команда, по номеру документа выведет номер полки, на которой он находится\n'
                   '- q: команда, для завершение работы\n>').lower()
    if choice == 'p':
        people()
    elif choice == 's':
        shelf()
    elif choice == 'q':
        print(' - До скорой встречи!')
        break
    else:
        print(' - Неизвестная команда, попробуйте выбрать из списка:')
```